# Content slightly moves when hovered

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, absolute

I have an absolute positioned element inside a div that is hidden (opacity:0), when hovering I set the opacity to 1. When the div ends the transition part of the content moves 1px down and the absolute positioned elements get 1px narrower.

This only happens on Google Chrome.

I made a small video to show what's happening
[image: example]

And this git to show the markup and styles: https://gist.github.com/lucasfercunha/9932819

Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in a small JSFiddle.

Comment: `margin:0;padding:0` ?

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` to `.post__meta`